# The Markdown editor chokes on $ characters in URLs

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, escape-character

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10789/weird-markdown-glitch), I had an issue with the Markdown formatting being corrupted by a $ sign in the URL. The fix was to escape the $ sign as %24.

There is seemingly no reason for this, as the $ sign is not a special character in either Markdown or URLs.

Twice now, Jeff has retagged the question as support, despite the answer being that there is a bug affecting this area (and therefore it should be tagged as bug). So I'm opening a question for just the bug, without any of the case-specific baggage.

Comment: Another example of the Markdown parser failing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10532/multiple-link-issue-in-a-superuser-question/10533#10533

Comment: if you have crazy URLs, you have to escape the content. 99% of users don't have this problem because most URLs are fairly sane. That's why it is [support] and not [bug].

Comment: A google search containing the $ sign is now a crazy URL?

Comment: sorry, $ in an URL is just not common enough to warrant supporting it; we whitelist characters and every new whitelisted char is a hole for an attack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is seemingly no reason for this, as the $ sign is not a special character in either Markdown or URLs.

I'm not so sure. If I'm not mistaken, http URLs follow the generic URI syntax, and that [lists](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) *$* as a reserved delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

The Javascript editor chokes on the following characters:

`*`, `$`, `\`, `[`, `]`, `^`, `'`, `"`, `{`, `}`, `\`

I'm sure there are others, but those are the ones right there on the keyboard for me to test.  Some of those are obvious and not bugs (`'` and `"`, for example, are used to provided title text).  I *could* test the server-side Markdown processor, but that'd be difficult and unpleasant.

The original [wmd editor](http://wmd-editor.com/demo) doesn't appear to have these bugs, which implies that it's something in the showdown engine.  I would imagine the server-side version was designed to mimic the preview editor as much as possible, which would explain why the bugs persist in the rendered posts.  That's just a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Perl program to take an URL, and return the sanitized version, that will hopefully work with Markdown.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

our %map;
our $swap_rx;
BEGIN{
  my $special = '%$()\' ?';
  our @special = (split '', $special);
  for my $chr ( @special, ':' ){
    my $ord = ord $chr;
    my $hex = unpack 'H2', pack 'v', $ord;
    $map{$chr} = uc $hex;
  }

  $special = quotemeta $special;
  $swap_rx = qr"[$special]";
}

for(@ARGV){
  s/($swap_rx)/'%'.$map{$1}/eg;

  if( /[a-z]{3,10}:/ ){
    undef while s(
      ([a-z]{3,10}:.*?)(:)//
    ){
      $1.'%3A//'
    }ex;
  }else{
    s/:/'%3A'/g;
  }
  print $_,"\n";
}
```

Feel free to use it however you like.

If you find any problems leave a comment.

<sub>It would be interesting to see a bookmarklet that does this.</sub>