# The layout breaks when colons are placed in links

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, design

Please, see the broken layout [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471354/sharing-a-gnu-screen-session/471377#471377) If you use links that contain two "http"-part like with the links in WayBack Machine, the SO-layout breaks.

**The original code was:**

```
Good tutorial [here][1]. See [this part][3] of the GNU screen manual on how to set ACL permissions. Give him whatever permission you think he needs, though I don't think you'd need to change it from the default that's given by `acladd`.

If the first link is broken, please, it is [here.][2] 


  [1]: http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php
  [2]: http://web.archive.org/web/20080118033211/http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php
  [3]: http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_8.html#SEC28
```

**The broken layout was:**

> Good tutorial here. See this part of
>   the GNU screen manual on how to set
>   ACL permissions. Give him whatever
>   permission you think he needs, though
>   I don't think you'd need to change it
>   from the default that's given by
>   acladd.
>
> If the first link is broken, please,
>   it is
>   http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes%5Fgnu%5Fscreen%5Ftutorial.php">here.

**Arised Question thanks to Kip informing about %3A**

Should colons be automatically rendered to %3A?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11943/the-markdown-editor-chokes-on-characters-in-urls/15580#15580

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the linked article by changing the colon in the URL to %3A.  I don't think colons are considered valid URL characters except in `://`, and `user:pass@` and `:portnum`.  But I think it's still a bug that the server-side markdown is generating such bad html (the client-side preview looks correct).

For the record, here is the markdown source of the page that was giving the problem:

```
Good tutorial [here][1]. See [this part][3] of the GNU screen manual on how to set ACL permissions. Give him whatever permission you think he needs, though I don't think you'd need to change it from the default that's given by `acladd`.

If the first link is broken, please, it is [here.][2] 


  [1]: http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php
  [2]: http://web.archive.org/web/20080118033211/http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php
  [3]: http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_8.html#SEC28
```

Which gets rendered like this:

---

Good tutorial [here](http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php). See [this part](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_8.html#SEC28) of the GNU screen manual on how to set ACL permissions. Give him whatever permission you think he needs, though I don't think you'd need to change it from the default that's given by `acladd`.

If the first link is broken, please, it is [here.](http://web.archive.org/web/20080118033211/http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_gnu_screen_tutorial.php)

Answer (score 1):

ok, we now auto-encode any colons at string position 7 or higher, that are *not* followed by 2 or more numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately Jeff, this breaks URLs that have to specify a port number ( example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414644/maximum-time-allowed-to-complete-authentication-has-been-exceeded ).