# Should "money" links like linkbucks be blocked on the Trilogy?

Tags: feature-request, spam, business-model

There has been recently a user answering (with more or less good things) to questions on Super User, with all his links to programs made by "linkbucks" (meaning he earns money on each click, because it forces you to see ads before the actual link).

Here is [an example](https://superuser.com/posts/123544/revisions).

Should this linkbucks site be added to some black-list?

Comment: Wow.  Not even smart enough to hide it with a tiny url.

Comment: While we're on this topic, this feature request still languishes like a poor maiden back at the castle while her knight fights a border skirmish: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/can-and-should-stack-overflow-automatically-rewrite-bit-ly-links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree these are nasty and unwanted, but I only support blacklisting if it's a recurring problem.

We have one data point; let's revisit this if it becomes pattern-ish.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll just poke that if it is indeed becoming more frequent.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that example is definitely spam.  Please flag it for moderator attention.  If the link eventually takes you someplace useful, you could just edit the answer to go directly there.

We have a blacklist of sites you're not allowed to link to, I'll ask Jeff to add this one.

Comment: Yes, I flagged already, and edited all links from this user out (he posted only that kind). But I'm wondering for future cases, if it would be interesting to forbid them fully.

Comment: @Gnoupi: I updated my answer.  Thanks for pointing this out, I had never heard of this site before.