# locate help here or where for specific question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be allowed to offer external incentive (bounty) for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97657/should-i-be-allowed-to-offer-external-incentive-bounty-for-questions)

One of my questions on stack overflow is a nice project and I need some expertise. WHile people answer very nicely when they can, i am prepared to pay for help. is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hire a consultant, or put it up on something like topcoder? You can put a bounty on a question, and you will get answers from motivated people, assuming you have points to give away. Another alternative would be to check out some of the profiles of top users in the domain, and try to contact them as consultants.