# Clean up on aisle [Dive into Python] 3?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, clean-up, broken-link

Since the author of Dive into Python and Dive into HTML5 [has apparently quit the Internet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/10/04/searching-for-mark-pilgrim/), we're going to need to clean up all of the Stack Overflow posts that link to these fine works.

- [Posts containing links to Dive into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdiveintopython.org%2F*%22)
- [Posts containing links to Dive into HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdiveintohtml5.org%2F*%22)

The [folks over at Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/l192g/searching_for_mark_pilgrim/c2oz682) have provided links to mirrors of these works. Can we get some community help in fixing these links?

Mirrors:

- [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html)
- [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.net/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintopython3))
- [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5))

Comment: Imagine if we just dumped those Dives into the tag wikis with a little editing along the way

Comment: This is why ragequitting sucks. Particularly if you have created useful artifacts for the world, taking your ball and going home is not cool. That said, surely there are mirrors?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Bill listed the mirrors in his post (edited to make them clearer).

Comment: @random: I love that idea. I overall love the idea to *abuse* the tag wikis to dump whole manuals there.

Comment: @PaddedCell - [The scala tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) is an example of an *awesome* way to do this.  Much better than dumping someone else's manual in there.

Comment: http://oppugn.us/posts/1272050135.html

Comment: @JeffAtwood thoughts on dumping the data into our tag wikis from the mirrors? Worried about retribution?

Comment: `DiveIntoPython != DiveIntoPython3`  Should we replace all "Dive into Python" links with links to "Dive into Python 3"?

Comment: @John For now I'd say to just replace the ones where we have a mirror to the original content.  We can go back and fix the older ones later if Mark decides to come back or if new mirrors appear.

Comment: [Speaking of mirrors...](http://web.archive.org/web/20110716181728/http://www.diveintopython.org/toc/index.html)

Comment: Wait what?  A network of sites crammed choc-a-block full of *really smart* technical programmers with, between them, a million person-years of experience and you're asking real humans to hand-edit a bunch of stuff?

Comment: @DanBeale See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup/99165#99165)

Comment: @DanBeale It does seem supremely automatable, but the API doesn't allow write access yet.

Comment: Okay, so for (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806366/cache-html-load-results-for-quicker-loading) this question, I just change the dive_into URL to (https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5) and mention Storage?

Comment: @DanBeale I've just been adding `.ep.io` to the Dive Into HTML5 URLs.  See my edit to see where that link now goes.

Comment: Okay, I'm doing some of the HTML5 questions and answers (page 7 onwards) but I do not have edit privs yet - should I continue and dump my edits into some queue to be checked, or is it better if I stop?  I don't want to make more work for others.

Comment: @DanBeale Sorry I didn't get back to your earlier.  Those edits should be fine to submit for approval.  They only take a second each to check and approve.

Comment: You might be interested in these searches: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A"http%3A%2F%2Fdiveintopython.org%2F%2a" (python) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A"http%3A%2F%2Fdiveintohtml5.org%2F%2a" (html5) - should catch the pretty links too.

Comment: @Shog9 That just makes me sad.

Answer (score 2):

The search queries above are great, but there'll be a few results at the end of this mass edit where people have put the URL in comments. At the moment I'm just leaving an extra comment. I don't know if anyone else has more privileges and can edit comments?

Other than that, I'm noodling my way through these. I've started with HTML5 questions.

Comment: Comments probably aren't worth worrying about, but to answer your question, only moderators have that kind of power, no regular (even 10k+) users.