# What does "your post was converted to a comment" mean?

Tags: discussion, comments, convert-to-comment

One of my accepted answers at Stack Overflow was converted to a comment saying "**your post was converted to a comment in Stack Overflow**." What does this mean?

I wonder why an accepted answer which worked needed to be dealt with by converting to a comment. Won't it help others in the future? Is there a list of possible causes?

Well I had important another question in my mind that happens to copy pasted answers. Is it allowed with refrence to the original author? I see a person with 2500 reputation copy paste all his answer and being linked to in a question. Since links to questions may not work always since answers or questions may be deleted was my point?

Comment: i guess your answer was too short, or just a link to another answer which the system figured was better as a comment [converted-to-a-comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118814/why-was-this-answer-converted-to-a-comment)

Comment: Link to the answer?

Comment: See a previous question.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108979/why-was-this-answer-converted-to-comments

Comment: Ultimately, does it really matter? This question was closed as *not a real question* and I'm sure with the meta attention it's getting, it will probably get deleted altogether soon enough.

Comment: "One of my accepted answers" @animuson, isn't it a grammatical mistake.

Comment: @Rinzler , downvotes on meta is consider as not agree with you. and my previous comment was not for you. see i have marked it for **animuson**

Comment: See: [Are upvotes and downvotes different on meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) People probably agree that your answer should have been converted to a comment, so they're *disagreeing* with your question which is implicitly contesting this decision on the part of a moderator. It's not a bad question, it was just a little hard to understand before it was edited (and you provided the link to the answer).

Comment: Please stop defacing your question. If you do this again, there will be consequences.

Comment: i want to delete this question its of no use

Comment: You can't delete it, it's been answered. It's obviously of *some* use, you originally commented to my answer that you didn't know that and had learned something. And if it was useful to you, it's likely to be useful to someone else. If it were really of no use, why did you ask it in the first place?

Comment: i didnt  know others wont like the question anyways i see the question i asked is duplicate only http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118814/why-was-this-answer-converted-to-a-comment  ya your answer was helpfull but i hate serial downvoting it pisses me off

Comment: This is not "serial downvoting"; that is when one user follows you around and downvotes a large number of your posts one after the other. That didn't happen here. I already explained why people downvoted this question. Just because something has been downvoted does not give you the right to delete it, and on Meta (as I already explained) it does not even imply that it is "of no use".

Comment: ok agreed ur point is correct     :(

Comment: @Lucifer "One of my accepted answers" is grammatically correct. In this instance, you are talking about a single accepted answer, from a choice of many accepted answers, so it is necessary to pluralise the word "answers". In the sentence, "One" refers to the singular object in discussion, "answers" refers to the group it was drawn from. I.e. "One answer out of many accepted answers".

Comment: @staticbeast thanks for downvoting please flag it to for all who downvote flag it to .

Comment: @Rinzler Actually, I didn't downvote, still haven't and I find it rude for you to assume and accuse, especially since there's no way to know.

Answer (score 17):

Because you posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734152/366904) that consisted *solely* of links to external resources. [Answers like this are not considered good answers for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) for a couple of reasons:

1. Links to external resources can go down at any time, rendering your answer useless.
2. Our goal here is to build up a library or "encyclopedia" of information about a particular topic. To that end, we expect answers (and questions too!) to be completely self-contained, meaning that they should be the only thing you have to read.

It is, however, completely fine to post related links as a comment, so rather than lose your contribution entirely by deleting the answer, the moderator clicked a button to automatically convert your answer into a comment.

If you wanted to turn this into an *answer*, you could edit it (even while deleted) and add a summary of the information contained in the link. At that point, you would only be providing the link for *reference*, not as the sole content of your answer. Once that's done, you could then flag the answer for moderator attention, explain what happened, and ask that it be undeleted. But in this particular case, I wouldn't worry too much about it, since that question has already been closed and isn't likely to be re-opened…

Comment: +1 - Very nice explanation. This could be great to put in the FAQ.

Comment: @jmort253, it **is** in the FAQ: [Why are some questions or answers removed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)

Comment: Yeah, I'm **tl;dr** to write FAQ answers. In other news, sorry @RivieraKid for plundering your suggested edit by rolling back the question. Didn't notice that counter in the top bar until it was too late. :-) Hope the system doesn't ban you from suggesting edits or something!

Comment: No worries - the rollback was the important thing anyway; besides, if it does, I'm sure I'll be back to complain :-)