# "your post was converted to a comment" has link to "deleted" page

Tags: bug, comments, help-center

One of my answers has

"your post was converted to a comment; see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) "

However the link redirects to the page

https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers  "Why and how are some answers deleted?"

which talking about deletion, but not converting to comment.

It should point to some more specific pages such as answer on [What does "your post was converted to a comment" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133593/what-does-your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-mean)

Comment: That question only covers a very small percentage of cases for an answer being converted to a comment. If something isn't covered in the help center article, you should point out what else needs included so it can be added there.

Comment: @animuson, I don't know other cases. Please list other cases as an answer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/133593/what-does-your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-mean or provide references where these cases are described.Nothing about converting to comment is said in the help center article.