# Internal link wasn't translated to title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, internal-links

In my question ["your post was converted to a comment" has link to "deleted" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273584/your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-has-link-to-deleted-page) the link to page [What does "your post was converted to a comment" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133593/what-does-your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-mean) wasn't automatically converted to title.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't happen, and I get annoyed and assume it's intentional for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link does not "onebox" because it's wrong.

That question does not exist in Meta Stack Overflow, but rather on Meta Stack Exchange. (This site)

The link you have in that other question of yours is:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/133593/what-does-your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-mean
```

If you put it in a browser, you will be redirected automatically to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133593/what-does-your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-mean` due to a check performed after MSE/MSO split.

So, the code that translates links to title is asking MSO "do you have question with ID of 133593? And it get a "no" as a response. hence no title. Putting correct link will result in correct title.

Question is, where you got that link from? If it was  somewhere on SE you should report and ask to fix. (Or of course edit yourself if from a different post.)

Comment: I believe,I've got the link from MSE search, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Links are converted automatically to *question* titles (one-boxed) if they are

- internal to the site you're posting on (and therefore do not reference a post on a different site) OR point to [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com); AND
- to a *question*, not an answer or a comment.

Meta.SE is different in that it one-boxes in both directions: links on Meta.SE pointing to questions across entire network as well as links on child-metas (not main sites) pointing to Meta.SE.

In your case, however, you linked to a post on `http://*.stackoverflow.*` that doesn't exist. It may have been a result of the the [MSE/MSO split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/168244) as `http://*.stackexchange.*` works.

Comment: First bullet is wrong: http://i.stack.imgur.com/awZau.png (posted in the answer box right here,  in MSE)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: True; [meta.se] is different. I've updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: I posted a link that auto converted on Meta.ELL and it linked to an answer on MSE. http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/2890/16318

Comment: @Catija: Correct. I've added that detail.

Comment: Still wrong. Links to MSE are not oneboxed on other sites, I just tried on arqade the link to this question and it did not onebox.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: This might be specific to Meta sites... could you try on Arqade's Meta?

Comment: Huh, that's correct.