# SO link in answer doesn't auto-translate to title

Tags: support, hyperlinks, title, internal-links

When I'm writing an answer in Stack Overflow, and I want to refer to another SO question, I can usually just past the URL into the answer, and it will be displayed as the title. But sometimes this doesn't work correctly.

I was editing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813384/1491895) today, and I pasted the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe` into the answer. In the preview this was shown as the question title, but when I saved the edit, it showed the raw URL rather than the title. It did correctly mark it up as a clickable link. But I had to go back in and paste the title by hand and use the URL as the link target with the link tool.

This seems related to [Internal link wasn't translated to title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273660/internal-link-wasnt-translated-to-title) but I don't think either of the answers there apply. This also happened a day or two ago.

Comment: Use HTTPS links.

Comment: That's probably it. I have lots of bookmarks saved for all the questions that I use as frequent dupes, and I created the bookmarks before the HTTP->HTTPS switch a couple of weeks ago. I'll see if I can do a mass fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all the Stack Exchange sites support `https://`, within the site if you use the URL with `https://` it will automatically parse the title.

I have modified your answer with `https://` and it parsed the title correctly. Please check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44813384/revisions).

Comment: I guess this is due to the switch a few weeks ago from HTTP to HTTPS as the default scheme for all Stack Overflow sites. But maybe the parser should still recognize the old style URLs. What's happening with all the answers that were written before the switch?

Comment: @Barmar all the links have been replaced using an automated script. It's mentioned in [the blog post describing the road to SSL](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/): "Once a site is moved to HTTPS (by enabling a feature flag), we then crawled the network to update the links to it. This is to both correct “Google juice” as we call it, and to prevent users eating a 301."

Comment: Thanks. I've done the global replace in my bookmarks file, so I should be good for the future. Not to mention I'm getting fewer 301's now when I go to SO sites.