# Enable internal link translation for all Stack Exchange communities

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, internal-links

On Meta Stack Exchange, I can post a link to any question on the Stack Exchange network, and it will be automatically translated into the correct question title.

- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-using-random-strings-print-hello-world` → [Why does this code using random strings print "hello world"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-using-random-strings-print-hello-world)
- `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88783/65907` → [Build a digital clock in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88783/65907)
- `https://superuser.com/q/792607/358766` → [Why does Windows think that my wireless keyboard is a toaster?](https://superuser.com/q/792607/358766)

However, on any other SE Community, internal links are only translated into titles if the link references another question on the same site.

For example, When posting on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), links to other questions on Code Golf will be converted to titles, while links to Stack Overflow will be ignored.

[image: Example Code Golf question]

According to *[Internal link wasn't translated to title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273660/351462)*, this is currently listed as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but I can't think of any drawbacks to enabling link translation for all sites.

**Can internal links be translated into titles regardless of site, just as they do here on Meta Stack Exchange?**

Comment: One of that linked question's answers also notes that you can do this on child metas with MSE posts, too. Also, I think that question is not very related. Shadow's answer makes it look like the OP was using the wrong link for the question.

Comment: I can't speak for the dev team, but I'm reasonably certain that cross-site queries are still somewhat problematic, making this [feature-request] somewhat more difficult/impractical than it sounds. Hopefully someone who knows better can chime in.