# Cleanup advice wanted

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Please see these two questions:-

[Clean up on aisle [Dive into Python] 3?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108450/clean-up-on-aisle-dive-into-python-3)

[Let Me Flag That For You - URL Shortener Cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup)

I'm going to have some spare time over the next couple of weeks and can trawl through these, but I need some advice.

**URL SHORTENERS**

- Any URL inside code tags will be left untouched.
- Any URL in comments will be left untouched and unflagged.
- Any URL leading to an [LMGTFY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) will be left but flagged.
- Any other URL will be followed, checked for life, and linked inline in the question / answer; the shortened URL will be gone.
- Any short URL leading to EvilSite will be left and flagged

Does that sound reasonable?  Anything wrong or bad in that list?  Anything missed?

What do I do about short URLs leading to dead sites?

**PYTHON / PYTHON 3**

I have no idea which DiveInto version to link to. Sometimes it's obvious (if it's about 2.4 then I don't link to Python3.)

So, should I just include links to both? (DiveIntoPython/DiveIntoPython3)?

Comment: Major props to you for helping out here! Everything under the URL Shortners heading sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: "I have no idea which DiveInto version to link to." If you can't figure it out just link to whatever one the old link pointed to.  The old link might not *work*, but you can still see where it went.

Comment: ***Waves magic HedgeMage wand of cleanup-blessing***  Go for it... the described changes will absolutely make the site better for everyone.  I second the recommendation from @John to use the version previously linked to as a guide to what you should link to at the new locations.