# Any way to massively edit broken GitHub Twitter Bootstrap links?

Tags: discussion, broken-link, twitter, github

Twitter [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) was moved from the [Twitter](https://github.com/twitter) organization to the [TWBS](https://github.com/twbs) organization. This has resulted in numerous broken links all over the Internet, and it would be nice if GitHub did something about it.

Nevertheless, Stack Overflow has a large number of links to issues on the Bootstrap project which are now broken (see this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9760366/revisions).

Could we look into replacing all `github.com/twitter/bootstrap/` with `github.com/twbs/bootstrap/`?

Or less agressively `github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/` with `github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/`?

Comment: You're calling out GitHub on a Meta SO post. Did GitHub Support already come back to you on what their end of the deal is?

Comment: I probably could have done more investigation, but I've seen this behavior for quite a while (maybe months?), so from pure observation it seems that they aren't taking care of it, but I could be wrong.  I would assume with such an obviously impactful move (bootstrap being so popular) that they would have taken care of this.  Put short, I'm assuming a bit and taking the 'short route' to fix the problem on SO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 2013-10-02, the redirects for issues and pull requests in the old Bootstrap repository appear to be functioning, so no edits are necessary.

---

Generally, there's *supposed* to be a redirect from the old GitHub repository to the new one in cases like this. This wasn't working after Bootstrap's transition to its new organisation, so someone [opened a relevant issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8993).

Since it was marked closed, I assume that they got things sorted out at the time, but as it's broken now I've gone ahead and asked if the current behaviour is expected. If it isn't and the redirect can be (re)fixed, then there's no need to edit anything as the links should just start working again once the problem is resolved.

If, on the other hand, nothing can be done, the best course of action is likely just to edit them as you come across them. The [last time something like this happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108450/clean-up-on-aisle-dive-into-python-3), it looks like the community was able to band together to get the job done, so an organised effort might be worthwhile if you were hoping to get it done sooner.

Unfortunately [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)'s current hardware appears to be insufficient for querying for the old URL against all of the post bodies on Stack Overflow, otherwise we could get a better feel for the scope of the issue. You can always just do a [site search for the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A*github.com%2Ftwitter%2Fbootstrap*) now that URL wildcards are supported, which I suppose makes more sense anyway.

Comment: Thanks for doing the proper thing and bringing it up on GitHub, I was too lazy ;)

Comment: Awesome, glad this got fixed!