# Is it possible to make bulk spelling corrections for loose -> lose?

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

There are currently [3500+ results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=loose+focus) for "loose focus" on Stack Overflow, the *vast* majority of which are misspellings of "lose focus".

Is this worth addressing, and if so, how?

I am aware of [other ongoing efforts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup) to perform bulk-cleanup of a large volume of posts, but I'm not sure  if the same thing is necessary here, or desirable by the community.

Comment: I'm amazed at how 3000 or so people cannot spell lose...

Comment: @SimonSheehan or the same person 3,000 times :)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the problem is common to every site in the SE network. Server Fault has lots of talk about "loosing connections", for example :|

Comment: The same problem is common to every site on the entire internet. Part of me wonders if lose -> loose is possibly the most common misspelling around.

Comment: No that would be its/it's or your/you're.

Comment: @Toomai I still think of "it's" instead of "its" because it's like agf's / meagar's / etc. and have to mentally beat myself into submission as I type. But I doubt that is nearly as easy to autocorrect as the loose / lose pair.

Comment: The problem with bulk corrections like this is their loose focus.

Comment: @Ben The question is, would there be fewer errors after a mass loose->lose correction? Would the change result in less than 3500 errors afterwards?

Comment: @meagar I understand and I would assume that significantly less than half of those "loose focus" statements are correct, but I would never would to auto-correct things like this unless A) it was a *serious* problem and B) it significantly impacted readability. IMO it's neither of these things and I'd hate to set precedent to autocorrect things based on this. I do like Truth's suggestion of making it a "low quality" style indicator that makes it show up in review though. If possible it would be a good inclusion in out "low quality" algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of other Q/A sites which have some very good bots built to address these kinds of issues. The bot identifies the potential misspelling, and batch displays it to a moderator or a community tool (such as the reviewing tool).

The problem can be fixed by the corresponding people then.