# Inline editing on search pages, too?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, search, inline-editor

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111839/is-it-possible-to-make-bulk-spelling-corrections-for-loose-lose). I think being able to edit inline, directly in search results, would be a great feature. (One use - people can identify *outrageously* common spelling errors like "to loose focus," search for them, and replace them inline when they have time.)

So... can it be added, please? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it could be implemented in such a way that it doesn't clutter the interface, I still think this is a very bad idea. Given that your intent was to basically find and replace spelling mistakes, an inline edit (if I understand you correctly) would not encourage people to *read* the post before editing it, leading to editing mistakes. I noticed several search results where "loose" wasn't a mistake at all, and if you were to correct all of them you may not notice that many of them are in fact correct.

Comment: Note "inline" not "mass" or "automatic".  He wants to make it easier, not autonomous.  The moderator still needs to pay attention to see that they are not mistakenly replacing the word.

Answer (score 6):

This is unlikely to happen, it's really not what search is for.  The [review section](https://stackoverflow.com/review?s=1) of the site, the moderator tools, etc. actually make sense to have editing inline, search...not so much.

It's only one click to get to somewhere you *can* inline edit the content, so the added complexity of the page and additional UI elements isn't justified in the search case.