# Edit that replaces a paid URL shortener rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I am relatively new to SO so I don't know all the nuances of the rules yet. I recently submitted my first edit which was rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/313353

Original post links to a page using a paid-per-click URL shortener service (similar to Adf.ly) and my edit replaces this link with the actual target link. Why was this edit rejected? I am under the impression that URL shorteners should be removed, especially ones that are paid. Please let me know if my assumptions are wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Data point: One of the people rejecting it was the OP; message: *this is not a permanent url and we do not want it posted.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters but the odd thing is "urlgone.com" sells itself on expiring the URLs after a fixed period of time.

Comment: @Flexo: I think that's the point.

Comment: @Flexo: Not odd at all; the OP doesn't want the target of the URL shorterner to be posted, and with a shortener that isn't permanent they hope to achieve that, I guess. (I have no stake in this, just reporting details that may of importance to the discussion.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - but the exact same thing (*"this is not a permanent url and we do not want it posted"*) can be said about the URL shortner too.

Comment: @Flexo: I've closed the question as too localized.

Comment: Ah, so it's especially abusive. You're easily in the right here but probably no point in trying to correct this specific question since it's a "debug for me" question

Comment: As for the other vote against your edit: I think that that editor misunderstood what the edit was about and thought you had replaced a legitimate URL with a spam URL instead (*This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.*).

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice one of the rejectors was OP. Thanks for the clarification guys.

Comment: In this case (I visited that question today, too) the shortener was also very ugly. At first I thought: Why would the OP point to the Amazon website until I found out that I have to view an ad before I can see the page with the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Quoted from an SE employee regarding URL shorteners:

> [They're not banned. We just hate them. We really, really hate them.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/166936)

You're in the right to correct the shortened URL. One of the few URL shorteners I would trust is Google (because it will stick around). But more generally URL shorteners make it hard to determine where a URL will go, they're slow, they're a second point of failure. They're no good to have around and there's no benefit to using them in a post either.

So yes, continue to correct shortened URLs, however as mentioned above this question is a lost cause in it's present state.

Comment: I don't remove them because I'm afraid they'll go dead, I remove them simply because I really, really hate them, even Google ones. No other reasoning necessary. :)

Comment: @animuson that's a valid reason as well. They're also *slow* as they introduce a redirect. There's no one reason to remove them

Comment: Accepted for directly confirming my general assumption. @animuson +1 Thanks for pointing out that OP rejected it, I had overlooked that and was confused at his rejection reasoning.

Comment: It's like counting cards in a Las Vegas casino. It's not against any laws or anything, you may just get beaten up and left for dead in a back alley somewhere for doing it.

Answer (score 21):

At this point, that question is not even a real question. We can't be expected to follow a link in order to figure out the problem. The post should expand more on the issue, possibly providing a screenshot of the width problem they're experiencing, and also pull in the relevant code where the problem is occurring.

Aside from that, the OP rejected it himself saying that it wasn't a permanent URL, **all the more reason to pull in information**. Once that URL goes down, that question will just be useless text on a page.

So I wouldn't worry about the URL shortener in this specific case.