# How to shorten/beautify referenced SO URLs

Tags: discussion, markdown, hyperlinks

One thing I love about Markdown is that it's possible to write content so
that if you follow a few rules, your content can be either converted to
(HT)ML and styled needed *but* still pretty much readable by itself.
(And just for myself, I silently add "on a 80-char terminal".)

So when I write/review posts on SO, I try to follow this quite strictly.

One thing bothers me though, are URLs.  Most of the time I adhere to
referenced URLs, the reference list being indented twith 2 spaces:

```
[Lorem Ipsum][1] is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

  [1]: http://www.lipsum.com/
```

This is nice until the link is long, like some links *to SO answers*:

```
If I [override `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`][1], then `get`/`set` don't
work.  How do I make them work?  Surely I don't need to implement them
individually?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict
-and-override-get-set/2390889#2390889
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict
-and-override-get-set/2390997#2390997
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622722/overriding-set-methods-in-
python/1622872#1622872
```

Do I have any options how to make the plain-text version less terrible?

- Regarding Markdown itself, is it possible to safely break the line?

  I don't really believe there is, but it would probably be the only option
  that would work for non-SO links.
- Regarding SO links, are there parts that could be stripped?
- <strike>Are there any "internal" SO URL shorteners?</strike> (That was
  a joke.  We all [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450), [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99136), [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660) hate URL shorteners.)

Comment: You can strip the title from the link. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/#2390889` will redirect to the same place as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict
-and-override-get-set/2390889#2390889`

Comment: When I visit your first example answer and click "share", I get `http://stackoverflow.com/a/2390889/474189`, which seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: @DuncanJones And even with that, the second number can be stripped off because it's just your user ID and won't do anything when pasted on the network itself. Makes for a conveniently short URL.

Comment: @DuncanJones oh, I forgot the "share" links.  It's always been puzzling me, though, why there must be *two* URLs, one that is in your Location bar and *different* one that is best for sharing. (*apart* from the "# fragment part")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I visit your first example answer (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-get-set/2390889#2390889`) and click on the "share" button, I get the following URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390889/474189

Which seems quite short and convenient to me. The second part is just my user-id, so we can strip that down to:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390889/

However, in general I would suggest you don't fret about the look and feel of the source of a question. It's more important that the question looks pleasant when viewed by others.

Comment: "I would suggest you don't fret about the look and feel of the source of a question" +1

Comment: *I would suggest you don't fret about the look and feel of the source of a question* From this point such fretting seem unnecessary, but in the end, it's more about semantics than about the looks of the source code. It kind of boils down to the "less is more" principle.  For example, why should *unnecessarily long* link be there/exist in the first place?  What if someone copies the link from the HTML version? Why should the link travel around with irrelevant information?

Comment: SE sites have very nice readable slugs for a reason, @Alois. I don't want to click a link to see what it links to, when I can simply hover to see the URL. Also, shortening the link will make my browser think I didn't visit it yet. So, no: please do NOT use short links when not needed.

Comment: *I don't want to click a link to see what it links to* I'm not fan of obscure links (in fact I hate them, especially if they obscure the host part), I'm fan of **unique** links.  Sure it would be best if the link was something like `http://stackoverflow.com/q/how-to-do-blah-blah/a/3` That wouldn't probably avoid collisions, though...