# Is providing links to redirecting advertising pages bad?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Is providing links to redirecting advertising pages like [AdfLy](http://adf.ly/) bad ? Those sites pay for clicking the shared link, but are showing advertisements during that. [For example that is shorten URL for stackoverflow.com](http://adf.ly/WgPuH). Can we use it in questions or/and answers ?

Comment: Please don't. In particular not within the SE network. We don't want to subject our users to ads that we can't control (the ones we do show, for example, are not animated or flash).

Comment: I see no reason to provide such links, other than trying to make money of it yourself which is really not the point of StackOverflow.

Comment: If you _so_, I will downvote your answer and not read any more.

Comment: See also: ["What to do about clickbank, adfly and similar “referral” programs?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122659/what-to-do-about-clickbank-adfly-and-similar-referral-programs). Personally, I remove these links on sight and replace them with direct links to the source material, same as I do with other link shorteners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't do that. If you have a link to share, as part of your otherwise self-contained content, make it a direct link. Don't use URL shorteners and especially not if they lead to advertisements first.

First of all I personally like to be able to see where a link will take me. And I generally won't click on anything that might seem suspicious.

And secondly, you wouldn't want your posts to be flagged for spam, which is not all that unlikely when an advertisement is the first thing someone sees.