# Resolve shorturls automatically

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can and should Stack Overflow automatically rewrite bit.ly links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/can-and-should-stack-overflow-automatically-rewrite-bit-ly-links)

It would be nice if SO kept a list of common url shorteners (there's a Firefox extension related to shorturls that contains a pretty extensive list, I don't remember its name though) and then, when used in a question/answer, replaced the shorturl with the real url or at least displayed the real URL in a tooltip when hovering the link.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shorting-services and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup