# Does the link to the chat appear only on the answered questions? Why, if so?

Tags: discussion, questions, chat, hyperlinks, unanswered-questions

For example, I see "X people chatting" link [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users):

> [image]

<sup>Also, wtf I'm the last poster in the Tavern? And why last message 54 mins ago? Clearly wrong. Last post was from rene and definitely not 54 mins ago.</sup>

While [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), this link is nowhere to be seen.

> [image]

I guess that this link appears only on answered posts, but that's unclear why.

---

Wait, I noticed no link in [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259050/as-a-moderator-should-i-re-flag-spam-thats-already-flagged-or-just-delete-it). So it also depends on age of the oldest answer to that question? Or just caching?

Comment: the last message thing is probs caching and the link in the sidebar is linked *from* that post.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Possibly caching; also see the edit: this darn caching seems to prevent such links from appearing in the recently answered questions.

Comment: Don't get me involved in this... Can you blur my avatar? Oh, it already is...