# What do we know about the Stack Exchange pharma spammer?

Tags: discussion, spam

I am creating this question to collect any relevant observations you can provide about the dominant spammer in the Stack Exchange network.

More specifically, I am asking about the spammer who currently dominates the [Metasmoke](http://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search) spam archive collected by the [Charcoal HQ volunteer anti-spam effort](http://charcoal-se.org/).

I welcome any answers including, but not limited to, insights on the following:

- What is their modus operandi?
- Where are they hosted?
- Where can we complain?
- How have they adapted their operations over time?

At this point, I am planning to post an answer of my own which however is necessarily tentative and incomplete.  I welcome any additional insights you can provide, with the ultimate goal of collecting enough evidence here to convince their upstream providers to cut them off (or equivalently, persuading them to just stop doing this).

Comment: Why do you assume this is a single operation? I don't get the impression this is an organized campaign (unlike [some previous and much larger spam operations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam) , or groups we know to be promoting the same family of products). While concentrated in India, these spammers are coming from all over the globe. If I had to guess, it's a range of different operations.

Comment: There was always spam, and always will be spam. We can't catch the spammers in real life, and even if we could, we can't do anything to stop them. Spam is legal in most countries as far as I know. So bottom line... nice effort, but waste of time. Spam won't bring SE down any time soon.

Comment: Yeah, we also cannot ever completely eradicate disease, so let's stop this silly business of drinking clean water.

Comment: @BradLarson I too thought originally that there were multiple operators, and I don't completely rule it out (see the first section of my answer) but there are too many commonalities -- they are working regular hours, enough to make "spam hour" a thing in Charcoal, and basically disappear during [holidays in India](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=38370057#38370057). Also, there is a handful of templates which are recognizable after staring at these for some 10 months now. The variations we see are better explained by A/B testing than by multiple operators IMHO.

Comment: In terms of volume, we don't currently have a good way to isolate these in Metasmoke, but assuming the 75% ratio in the sample I looked at is roughly representative (or even if it's just 50%!) we are talking tens of thousands of posts. Does your NHL example really compete with that?

Comment: (NFL, whatever; shows how important sports are to me.)

Comment: I love your idea to stop drinking clean water. I never drink water unless there's something dissolved in it, like glucose or ethanol.

Comment: @BradLarson For example, [this Smoke Detector rule](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/106) gets basically all Indian pharma hits, it captures a couple of the templates they keep on using. Can you postulate a division of the posts returned by that report into separate operations, or perhaps the reported posts vs. other pharmaceutical spam? I don't think I can.

Comment: In the graph in that report, also notice the slow beginning of the week after June 24th, which was apparently a public holiday in their region (not nationally celebrated, but a couple of days off in some parts of India). (Unfortunately, the report is dynamically generated, so this detail will scroll off in a week or two.)

Comment: @tripleee - Reviewing the content and style of these, many of them do seem to be from one organization, or at least the content is seeded by one source. Metasmoke looks like it caught all instances of this spam on SO, so there aren't any beyond this. That's 3 posts in 7 days on SO. In contrast, the NFL spammers were posting 100-200 posts a day on SO alone, and were hammering other sites even harder. Not saying these folks aren't an annoyance, but it's the disruptive spam attacks that cause the most problems. The "snowshoe" nature of the pharma spammers makes them difficult to completely block.

Comment: Yeah, you could say SmokeDetector is becoming increasingly specialized to identify this particular strain of spam, though we obviously strive to capture the other 20-40% as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm posting a separate answer to note that this organization seems to have finally stopped spamming the Stack Exchange network.

Some vestiges of pharma spam are still visible in Charcoal's statistics, but this specific operation seems to have ceased operations last year, as witnessed by this statistic:

[image: #drugs posts per month, down to 35 from over 200 in April 2021]

([The report is available in metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/data/sql/queries/98-drugs-posts-per-month-last-year-and-a-half) but you need the "core" role for Blazer privileges.)

Answer (score 19):

We currently only have circumstantial evidence, so it's not exactly clear even how to identify which *precise* messages belong to this spam operation (or even if it's a single operation, or competing gangs based in the same region).  What we can say with confidence is that business hours in India and e.g. bank holidays in India shape the amounts of spam we see, enough to conclude that the majority of spam which gets past the Stack Exchange spam filter SpamRam is sent from India.

The spammer operates on the order of hundreds of domain names, many with names including "health", "supplements", "diet", "hair", "muscle" etc but also many with odd or completely unrelated names.

Currently, the majority of these domains appear to be registered and hosted by http://namecheap.com/, though many are also on Cloudflare, a provider who protects their clients' sites against DDoS attacks etc by appearing as the infrastructure front.

The posts usually lead to a "blog site" with "reviews" of various products.  Typically, only one of them will click through to an actual order form (and some of the others will have "bad reviews" along the lines of "total scam") hosted on a separate set of sites, often with offers directed exclusively at North American customers (US only, Canada only, etc).

As a quick case study, looking at the 69 ostensible spam posts handled by the Charcoal volunteers during the last six hours, we see

- three apparent false positives;
- four posts which were rude or otherwise abusive, but not strictly spam;
- fifteen posts with some different promotion apparently unrelated to this operation;
- and thus 47 posts all apparently by this single (?) operation.

The promotions and domain names are rotated from day to day, so the following is probably not directly representative, but hopefully still somewhat illustrative.

The following apparent product names are promoted (obfuscated with invisible [U+00AD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AD/index.htm) characters to avoid helping their SEO ranking; this means you won't be able to usefully copy/paste anything to a search box from here):

- b­e­l­l­a r­o­s­e r­x - 12 posts
- n­e­u­r­o x­r, ne­ur­o bo­os­t i­q - 6 posts each
- d­sn p­r­e w­o­r­k­o­u­t, t­e­s­t­r­e­x - 3 posts each
- m­a­g­n­e­t­i­q­u­e h­a­i­r g­r­o­w­t­h, te­st­fac­tor, m­a­r­v­e­l­s o­f n­a­t­u­r­e, a­m­a­b­e­l­l­a - 2 posts each
- cu­r­a­l­in, p­x­l m­a­l­e e­n­h­a­n­c­e­m­e­n­t, p­u­r­e s­l­i­m 3­6­5, c­e­l­e­x­a­s, a­c­t­i­v­a­t­r­o­l, a­l­p­h­a t­e­s­t­o m­a­x, m­u­s­c­l­e r­a­m­p­a­g­e, f­o­l­l­i­c­l­e r­x, e­r­e­c­t­i­g­e­n - 1 post each

On a different day, you would see dozens of other products instead -- just like the domain names, there are hundreds of these.

In these posts, we see the following domain names (again, obfuscated to avoid SEO and thus blocking straightforward copy+paste):

- NS and hosting by Namecheap domains (NS namecheaphosting.com, hosting web-hosting.com)

  - g­u­i­d­e­ me ­s­u­p­p­l­ements .com - 4 posts (all time 112)
  - h­e­a­l­t­h­ f­l­y­ u­p .com - 3 posts (all time 228)
  - h­e­a­l­t­h­y ­m­­i­n­i­ h­ub .com - 1 post (all time 27)
  - h­e­a­l­t­h­y­ or­d­er .org - 3 posts (all time 144)
  - h­e­a­l­t­h­ p­u­r­e ­l­i­v­e­s .com - 2 posts (all time 168)
  - h­e­a­l­t­h­ c­a­r­e­ s­u­p­ c­h­a­t .com - 1 post (all time 15)
  - w­e­l­l­n­e­s­s ­i­n­c­r­e­d­i­b­l­e .com - 4 posts (all time 11)
  - s­u­p­p­l­e­m­e­n­t ­4­ h­e­l­p .com - 4 posts (all time 195)
  - v­i­s­i­t­ 4­ s­u­p­p­l­e­m­e­n­t­s .com - 1 post (all time 4)
  - g­e­t­ s­t­y­l­es .org - 2 posts (all time 2)
  - o­r­a­l­ h­e­a­l­t­h­ p­l­us .com - 2 posts (all time 231)
- NS and hosting by Cloudflare

  - r­e­v­o­l­y­n­ f­r­a­nce .com - 1 post (all time 12)
  - m­i­r­a­ h­e­­a­l­t­h­ g­a­r­c­i­n­i­a­ b­l­o­g.com - 1 post (all time 60)
  - n­u­t­r­a­ s­u­n­ n­­a­t­u­r­a­l­ g­r­e­e­n­ c­l­e­a­n­s­e­ b­l­og .com - 1 post (all time 15)
  - m­y­ l­a­v­i­v­e­ e­y­e ­s­e­rum .com - 1 post (all time 68)
  - d­r­o­z­ h­e­a­l­t­h­ blog .com - 1 post (all time 22)
  - r­e­a­l­ c­o­l­o­n­ c­l­e­a­n­s­i­n­g­ w­o­rks .com - 1 post (all time 151)
  - c­o­l­o­ d­e­t­o­x­ p­l­u­s­ f­rance .net - 1 post (all time 25)
  - r­h­i­n­o­ r­x­ 9­0­ e­v­e­n­i­n­g­ b­l­o­g .com - 2 posts (all time 53)
  - m­u­s­c­le­ b­u­i­l­d­i­n­g­ b­uy .com - 1 post (all time 130)
- GoDaddy domains (NS by domaincontrol.com, hosting secureserver.net)

  - s­u­p­p­l­e­m­e­n­t ­o­­f­­­f­e­r­s .org - 1 post (all time 188)
  - f­a­c­t­s­ 4 ­s­u­p­p­l­e­­m­e­n­t .com - 1 post (all time 62)
  - m­e­n­s­ h­e­a­l­t­h­ s­­u­p­p­l­e­m­­e­n­t .info - 1 post (all time 18)
  - c­r­a­z­y­ b­u­l­k­ s­t­a­­c­k­s .com - 1 post (all time 36)
  - h­e­a­l­t­ s­u­p­p­l­e­m­e­n­t­s­ r­e­v­i­e­w­s .info - 1 post (all time 71)
- NS by iserverplanet.com, hosting lstn.net

  - h­e­a­l­t­h­ i­t­ c­o­n­g­­r­­­e­s­s .com - 1 post (all time 12)
- NS by hostgatorwebservers.com, hosting webhostbox.net

  - e­v­e­r­g­r­e­e­n­ y­o­u­t­h .com - 1 post (all time 1)
- NS by radixhosting.com, hosting mycpanelcloud.co.uk

  - b­e­s­t­ h­e­a­l­t­h­ d­i­e­t .com - 2 posts (all time 104)
- NS and hosting by Digital Ocean

  - s­u­p­p­l­e­m­e­n­t­s­ v­e­r­d­i­c­t .com - 1 post (all time 10)

(The all-time stats are just for body hits -- there may be some additional ones which were only in the title of a post.)

I'll reiterate that this is not statistically representative or anything, just a quick case study to help us see some broad patterns.  Specifically, the favorite hoster is definitely Namecheap, but there is also a clear strategy to spread the load across multiple hosting providers (presumably as a precaution against getting thrown out by some of them, but also probably to get past some broad IP-based blocks).

Informally, it seems that the Cloudflare sites are probably also dominantly hosted by Namecheap in the end, but there isn't really any way to find out.

Whois registrations for these domains are generally anonymized, but those which aren't have usually revealed an Indian phone number and an address in Delhi (though they all seem to be slightly different).

We regularly see careless formatting, apparently suggesting manual copy+paste errors in the posts, so my personal conclusion is that this is an organization which specializes in affiliate spam using cheap and presumably not very heavily trained human labor.

Visiting a few of the URLs from these posts via an anonymizing proxy gets me the following.

- h­e­a­l­t­h ­c­a­r­e­ s­u­p­ c­h­a­t .com / e­r­e­c­t­i­g­e­n / gets me a 404 error page suggesting I try the home page instead

  - Top page contains a number of "reviews" but the top one is bigger than the others and promotes "A­l­p­h­a X­R". However, there is no order banner there.
  - Clicking through to various older posts finally gets me one with a big banner click-through for "J­u­l­l­e­n" which redirects to w­w­w.p­l­a­t­i­n­u­m­b­e­a­u­t­e.com which is hosted by Cloudflare. "Available to CA residents only" and a Canadian flag.
- h­e­a­l­t­h­ p­u­r­e­ l­i­v­e­s .com / n­e­u­r­o-x­r / is a working click-through to an order form hosted at t­r­y­n­e­u­r­o­x­r.c­om whose NS is with apxserver.com but the IP address is again in Namecheap netspace.  There is no explicit regional targeting but the address form requires you to pick a US state from a dropdown. (This is a common mistake on US-made sites which ostensibly target a worldwide audience, so it's not necessarily intentional.)
- o­r­­a­­­l­ h­e­a­l­t­h­ p­l­u­s .com / m­a­r­v­e­l­s-o­f-n­a­t­u­r­e-g­a­r­c­i­n­i­a / is a 404, suggesting some recent posts on the site I might like instead.

  - The top one promotes a similar product but does not have the click-through banner.
  - Clicking around, I find about four pages back one with a banner, promoting "n­a­t­u­r­e­s t­r­i­m g­a­r­c­i­n­i­a". Clicking that takes me to an order form at b­u­y­t­h­i­n­s­e­c­r­e­t.com whose whois record is live and informative, and indicates hosting by Rackspace.  I could not find any explicit geographical targeting clause but again, the order form requires you to have an address in a Canadian province.

**Update:** Belatedly, I got an answer (of sorts) from Namecheap.  I'm noting it here because it contains some implicit advice for our next complaint.

> From: Namecheap Legal & Abuse Team <abuse@namecheaphosting.com>
>   Reply-To: abuse@namecheaphosting.com
>   To: (redacted)
>   Subject: [#ZTI-111-23331]: Spamming customer of yours
>   Date: Tuesday, September 19, 2017 09:37
>
> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your email. Unfortunately, we are not able to
>   investigate the spam cases posted on forums or social networks. We are
>   not able to check if the domain owner is involved in spam activity or
>   not. Please understand that suspending the domain will not prevent the
>   spambot from posting the messages.
>
> We highly recommend you to contact the administrator of the forum.
>   They should be able to ban the user who posts the messages and resolve
>   the issue.
>
> Should you have further questions, please let us know.
>
> ____________
>   Regards, Nataly Bondarenko
>   Legal & Abuse Department
>   Namecheap.com
>
> Ticket Details
>   ---------------------------------
>   Ticket ID: ZTI-111-23331
>   Department: Hosting -- Legal and Abuse
>   Type: Issue

Comment: The Namecheap [terms of service](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9196/5/how-and-where-can-i-file-abuse-complaints) look like they actually welcome spammers and will not take action, but I'm getting in touch with them and Cloudflare at this point.

Comment: Just FYI... actually including the sites here means that you're doing essentially what they were trying to do...

Comment: @Mithrandir They are obfuscated, as noted in the answer text already. You will find that there are invisible characters which break the links to the actual product and domain names.

Comment: Ah. Missed that. Whoops.

Comment: Submitted ticket #ZTI-111-23331 to Namecheap hosting.

Comment: Also filled in the Cloudflare abuse form.  They only allow URLs from a single domain to be posted as evidence for a single report so I picked the rhino one.

Comment: Also complained to GoDaddy now; they too allow for a single URL, so I picked the first one in the list of domains hosted by them (exotically, in Spanish; https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/76819)

Comment: Yeah, spammers, bad, go get em... yeah.  So.  You got any of that e­r­e­c­t­i­g­e­n?