# Pharma spam gang switching to Google sites

Tags: discussion, spam, abuse

The pharma spammer gang <sup>[see earlier post by myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298538/what-do-we-know-about-the-stack-exchange-pharma-spammer)</sup>, who continue to aggressively target the Stack Exchange family of sites, has recently transitioned to promoting links to pages hosted by Google Sites.

A [Metasmoke search for `sites.google.com`](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=sites.google.com) over the spam reports on the Stack Exchange sites indexed by the [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org) anti-spam volunteer effort currently returns 20 results, the latest four of which are all similar. Currently, the oldest of these is 14 days old, but the other 3 arrived in the last 3 days. This is looking vaguely like an escalating trend.

In other words, it seems like this spam gang is now inceasingly experimenting with sites hosted by Google, presumably to reduce their risk of having their main sites disconnected.

The [Google Sites abuse report form](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/116262?hl=en) is slightly hard to find, and doesn't really allow us to communicate any details to Google.  In fact, it requires you to visit the offending site (and hope it doesn't contain any malicious JavaScript) and click "Report Abuse" in the site footer.

I'm creating this question to collect ideas for how to give Google's abuse team a good picture of the overall problem with this persistent spam gang and their recently changed tactic.

How can we best get in touch with Google to report this?

<sub>See also [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) for a bit of background about Charcoal and Metasmoke.</sub>

Comment: In desperation, I filled in the "illegal material" form at https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_legalother?product=sites and should recieve an email from the ignorebot shortly. Violating the Google Sites terms is certainly not a case for the public prosecutor but ... there really needs to be a way to report this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The Google abuse forms are hard to find so you want to rectify that situation here? Unless I misunderstand, this doesn't seem to belong here.

Comment: I think he wants awareness of the spammers so people know that we should whack em... or let team smokey know so they can be fried. Or if someone knows a better way to report em

Comment: The question is, is there a way to contact Google which I don't know about, perhaps in particular a back channel between Stack Exchange staff and Google?