# Very strange comment bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

Look at the final comment on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52566/why-does-stackoverflow-not-support-netscape-navigator-4-7-closed) question.

What happened to it? I simply typed:

```
[this](http://web.archive.org/web/19990117032727/http://www.google.com/)
```

...and it leaves a funny string after it:

```
 google.com" rel="nofollow">
```

*Plus the link doesn't work!*

Comment: By the way, I edited the comment, so it's no longer an example of the problem.

Comment: If you want, try posting another comment with that string.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the colon in the second http:// ; this is fairly typical for "urls that contain `http://`"

`[this](http://web.archive.org/web/19990117032727/http%3A//www.google.com/)`

We [handle this in the post body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21535/colons-in-link-urls-redux) but comments are lighter.

**Edit:** This has been fixed a while ago to also work in comments.

Comment: [this](http://web.archive.org/web/19990117032727/http%3A//www.google.com/)